# making function if database is not connect then logout user

Tags: php

I have following code for connecting to database. And i see many error when sometime connection failed to connect. well that i have hide by putting `error_reporting(0);` but i know its not solution.

**db.php**

```
class DB {
    protected $db_name = 'demo';
    protected $db_user = 'root';
    protected $db_pass = 'root';
    protected $db_host = 'localhost';   
    public function connect() {
        $connection = mysql_connect($this->db_host, $this->db_user, $this->db_pass);
        mysql_select_db($this->db_name);
        return true;
    }
```

then i have one file **inc.php** which i include on every page.

```
require_once 'db.php';
$db = new DB();
$db->connect();
//start the session
session_start();
```

Now i am confused where i include `die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());` also i want to `header("Location: logout.php");` if anyhow connection die.

Thank you

Comment: why you are hiding the error instead of solving it?

Comment: Hiding error in production server is must for many security reason.

Comment: yes error its all related to connection failed so thats what i am trying to solve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace:

```
public function connect() {
    $connection = mysql_connect($this->db_host, $this->db_user, $this->db_pass);
    mysql_select_db($this->db_name);
    return true;
}
```

To:

```
public function connect() {
    $connection = mysql_connect($this->db_host, $this->db_user, $this->db_pass);
    if(!$connection){
        //die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
        return false
    }if(!mysql_select_db($this->db_name)){
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

**inc.php**

```
require_once 'db.php';
$db = new DB();
$con = $db->connect();
if(!$con){
    header("Location:logout.php");
    exit();
}
```

Comment: after 'die', what's the use of return false?

Comment: main is logout.php that i really need to set.

Comment: @ViPiN only need to use one of them either die or return false.

Comment: @deerox i have updated my answer too that you can see. i have also commented that line because no need of die.

Comment: One suggestion I have here is you want to have error handling for `mysql_select_db` as well, because if that failed then in this case the `connect` function will still return true.

Answer (score 1):

I think it would be better if your `connect` function returns the `$connection` object if the connection and select database operation are successful and returns false if any of those fail.  Then in your calling page/function check if the result is `$connection`, if it is then proceed, otherwise do the redirection.

Something like following:

```
public function connect() {
    $connection = mysql_connect($this->db_host, $this->db_user, $this->db_pass);
    if (!($connection && mysql_select_db($this->db_name, $connection)) {
        // Log the error mysql_error()
        return false;
    } 

    return $connection;
}
```

And in your calling page/function:

```
$connection = $db->connect();
if (!$connection) {
    header("LOCATION: logout.php"); exit();
}

// Use your $connection variable here onwards where required.
```

Finally make a note that `mysql_` extensions are deprecated.  Start using `mysqli` or `PDO`

Answer (score 1):

mysql_select_db returns TRUE on success or FALSE on failure.

```
public function connect() {
    $connection = mysql_connect($this->db_host, $this->db_user, $this->db_pass);
    return mysql_select_db($this->db_name);
}
```

Then for your inc.php

```
require_once 'db.php';
$db = new DB();
if (!$db->connect()) {
    header("LOCATION: logout.php"); exit();
}
//start the session
session_start();
```

Answer (score 1):

If the connection isn't established, then $connection will equal FALSE, so:

```
if( $connection === FALSE ) {
    die( "Could not connect: " . mysql_error() );
}
```

However, the mysql_* functions are deprecated.  If you're working on an existing application, your best quick bet is to replace all mysql_* functions with their mysqli_* counterparts.  If this is a new application, I'd highly recommend switching to PDO.  Your connect statement would look like this:

```
$connection = new PDO( "mysql:dbname={$this->db_name};host={$this->db_host}", $this->db_user. $this->db_pass );
```

If the connection fails, a PDOException is thrown.  You can find out more about establishing PDO connections and catching the errors [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.construct.php).